# Generic type on remove method of collection in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections

For some weird reason, I want to implement a Collection from Java Util and with a generic type of everything, includes remove and contains, which for backward compatibilities reasons, they didn't do it at all, so I want to try myself. Here is what the code I want to look like:

```
public class MyTest<E> implements Collection<E>{

    @Override
    public <T> boolean remove(T t){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> boolean contains(T t){
        return true;
    }

}
```

As my research going on, I understand that this code eventually going to have the erasure like `remove(Object) of type Collection<E>`
but java simply seems like not accepting it instead but keep asking to override the method with Object as argument. So I'm asking if anyone knows anyway to work around it or directly with this

Comment: If you look at the JavaDoc for `Collection`, you will see that `remove()` is indeed declared with a parameter of type `Object`. If you want `MyTest` to implement `Collection<E>`, you will have to implement `remove()` with that parameter -- there is no way around it. You could, though, overload `remove()`, and declare a parameter of type `E`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have this implementation of `Collection` as in Java the arguments cannot use covariance or be redefined and `Collection` defines these two methods like that :

```
boolean remove(Object o);
boolean contains(Object o);
```

If you want to implement the `Collection` interface, you should implement these method as these are specified :

```
public class MyTest<E> implements Collection<E>{

     ... 
    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object  o){
       . . .
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o){
       . . .
    }
     ...     
}
```